# adding images to in react with dynamic links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have created react app using create-react-app , there is a component which need to be reused multiple times, this component contain `<img>` tag, image is different for each instance of the component.
I am passing image path as **imagePath** prop from parent to child component and then that child need to load image from that path. 
i can not use

```
import image from imagePath
```

because i don't know the path until component is build, and import statement don't work within component body.

I tried doing`<img src={imagePath}>`
that also don't work, can you point me to right direction?

adding code for further clarification

**first** approach it doesnt work. content is object passed by parent and content.image have value of ./images/keeper.PNG

```
    import React from 'react'; 
import image from './images/keeper.PNG'

    export default function Project(props)

    {

        return <div className='projectContainer'  >
            <div className='projectImage'>
                <img src={props.content.image}
            alt ='' />
            </div>
            <div className='.projectDescription'>
                <h4>{props.content.name}</h4>
                <p>{props.content.intro}</p>
                <h5>Technologies and problems</h5>
                <p>{props.content.tech}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div> }
```

**second**  methond `<img src={image} alt ='' />` it works fine and show image but as stated above i don't know image path before the component is created

Comment: add more code please.

Comment: The latter way should work, what's inside imagePath?

Comment: will you please add the code

Comment: imstead of import. sent the image url as props from parent componet.It will work.

Comment: @Ramesh full path to that image.

Comment: @Lutf Did any of the answers solve your problem? If not then update your question with the parent component especially the part where you're passing the props.

Comment: @PRADIPGORULE added more code can you see again please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using it this way, where you can pass the imagePath via props

```
<img src={require(`${props.imagePath}`)} />
```

This alone will do the job.

> When using Webpack you need to require images in order for Webpack to
>   process them, which would explain why external images load while
>   internal do not, so instead of img src= {"/imagePath"}  you need to
>   use img src= {require('/imagePath')}  replacing imagePath with the
>   correct image name for each of them. That way Webpack is able to
>   process and replace the source img.

Comment: if you do it this way , you will have to this everywhere in the file, where you intend to use the same image , this is bad code quality

Comment: @Coderboi, I did not get you. how will you be using the same image if you are passing the image url via props?

Answer (score 1):

Sample

Parent component

```
let image = 'https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/intro-video-poster@2x.jpg'

function Parent(){
 return <Child image={image}/>
}
```

Child component

```
function Child(props){
 return <img src={props.image} alt="icon-image" />
}
```

or

directly if you import in component

import imagePath from './image.jpg';

```
   function Child(props){
     return <img src={imagePath} alt="icon-image" />
    }
```

Comment: added code , can you tell me why this method doesn't work for me?

Comment: @Lutf if you have imported image then just do this src={image} instead of src={props.content.image}.

Comment: that is just to show that image path is working, i need many instances of this component which render different images so i need to get image path from props